# Pivot Table Construction

Tags: sql

I am attempting my first pivot table via sql and not getting very far.  My table contains multiple fields but I am working with three Registration varchar(8), dateoffix date, Submitted int.
I want to show a list of registrations and the count of submits for each day or day in the where clause.

[image]

```
USE Telemetry ; Go
SELECT * FROM
   (
   SELECT Registration
        , day(dateoffix) day
        , Submitted
   FROM   GPSPositions
   WHERE  dateoffix > DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()
   ) 
 ) PIVOT (   CAST(sum(Submitted) AS Int) count   
             FOR day > DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
         )
   ORDER BY [day] DESC
```

Comment: Don't bother with `pivot`.  Just use conditional aggregation.  `pivot` adds no new functionality and is not particularly concise.

Comment: Hi Gordon, as my post suggests I am no sql guru,  can you give me an example of how this could be achieved given my table structure.

Comment: How are you presenting the data? Many UI layers (winforms, ASP.NET, reports, etc.) have libraries that make pivoting much easier than it is in SQL. You just query the data normally and the display layer will do the pivoting for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you get a bigger list of combinations sometimes pivot is easier to write than conditional aggregation.

In Oracle your statement would look like

```
SELECT * FROM
   (
   SELECT Registration
        , day(dateoffix) day
        , Submitted
   FROM   GPSPositions
   WHERE  dateoffix > DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()
   ) 
 ) PIVOT (   sum(Submitted)  
             FOR Registration in ('123ABC','213ABC','642CBD')
         )
   ORDER BY [day] DESC
```

With conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT day
     , sum(case when Registration = '123ABC' then Submitted end) as "123ABC"
     , sum(case when Registration = '213ABC' then Submitted end) as "213ABC"
     , sum(case when Registration = '642CBD' then Submitted end) as "642CBD"
from
   (
   SELECT Registration
        , day(dateoffix) day
        , Submitted
   FROM   GPSPositions
   WHERE  dateoffix > DATEADD(day, -2, GETDATE()
   ) 
group by day
ORDER BY [day] DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas please give me a short time to test against my tables.